# 16-bit ALU: try to change operation code, but results still remain the same

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, alu

I am trying to write a 16-bit ALU. I have compiled everything successfully, but when the operation code `alu_code` changes, the result `C` stays the same (the first operation result).
Here's my code for ALU:

```
module ALU (
    input [15:0] A, B,
    input [4:0] alu_code,
    output reg [15:0] C,
    output reg overflow
);

wire [1:0] over;
wire signed [15:0] As, Bs, Bs2s;
wire signed [15:0] C_add, C_sub;
wire [15:0] C_addu, C_subu;
wire [15:0] B2s;
wire overflow_temp;

assign B2s = ~B + 1;
assign As = A;
assign Bs = B;
assign Bs2s = ~Bs + 1;

CLA add(.A(As), .B(Bs), .Sum(C_add), .overflow(overflow_temp));
CLA addu(.A(A), .B(B), .Sum(C_addu), .overflow(overflow_temp));
CLA sub(.A(As), .B(Bs2s), .Sum(C_sub), .overflow(overflow_temp));
CLA subu(.A(A), .B(B2s), .Sum(C_subu), .overflow(overflow_temp));

always @(alu_code or A or B) begin
    case(alu_code)
    00000 : C = C_add;
    00001 : C = C_addu;
    00010 : C = C_sub;
    00011 : C = C_subu;
    endcase
end

assign over = {overflow_temp, C[15]};

always @(*) begin
if (over == 2'b01) overflow = 1;
else overflow = 0;
end
endmodule

module CLA (
    input [15:0] A, B,
    output [15:0] Sum,
    output overflow
);

wire c1, c2, c3;

CLA4bit CLA1 (.A(A[3:0]), .B(B[3:0]), .Cin(1'b0), .Sum(Sum[3:0]), .Cout(c1));
CLA4bit CLA2 (.A(A[7:4]), .B(B[7:4]), .Cin(c1), .Sum(Sum[7:4]), .Cout(c2));
CLA4bit CLA3(.A(A[11:8]), .B(B[11:8]), .Cin(c2), .Sum(Sum[11:8]), .Cout(c3));
CLA4bit CLA4(.A(A[15:12]), .B(B[15:12]), .Cin(c3), .Sum(Sum[15:12]), .Cout(overflow));

endmodule


module CLA4bit(
    input [3:0] A, B,
    input Cin,
    output [3:0] Sum,
    output Cout
);

wire [3:0] P, G, C;

assign P = A ^ B;
assign G = A & B;

assign C[0] = Cin;
assign C[1] = G[0] | (P[0] & C[0]);
assign C[2] = G[1] | (P[1] & G[0]) | P[1] & P[0] & C[0];
assign C[3] = G[2] | (P[2] & G[1]) | P[2] & P[1] & G[0] | P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0];
assign Cout = G[3] | (P[3] & G[2]) | P[3] & P[2] & G[1] | P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & G[0] | P[3] & P[2] & P[1] & P[0] & C[0];

assign Sum = P ^ C;

endmodule
```

Here is the testbench:

```
module tbALU();

reg [15:0] A, B;
reg [4:0] alu_code;
wire [15:0] C;
wire overflow;

ALU uut(A, B, alu_code, C, overflow);

initial begin
A = 8'hAA; B = 8'hAA;
#50; alu_code = 0;
#50; alu_code = 1;
#50; alu_code = 2;
#50; alu_code = 3;
end
endmodule
```

The waveform of `C` is just like what I said; it never changes corresponding to change of operation.

Comment: The code you posted will not compile.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to paste my CLA adder! Updated.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues:

- `@(alu_code or A or B)` should be `@*` as `C` depends on `C_add`,`C_addu`,`C_sub`,`C_subu` and not directly `A` or `B`. By using `A` and `B` in the sensitivity list, you create a race condition between the always block that assigns `C` and the CLA modules. `@*` (or synonymous `@(*)`) is automatic sensitivity, and you should use `always @*` for just about all combinational blocks. Specify the sensitivity list for combinational logic is should only be used for coding in the old IEEE1364-1995 style or obscure non-synthesizable bus-functional-models. Better than `always @*` would be to use SystemVerilog's `always_comb`
- There are multiple drivers on `overflow_temp`. If there are conflicting values being driven, the result will be `x`. There should be only one driver per output. You can OR, MUX, or perform other logic to the output with other logic outside of the connection.
- The `case` statement has `00010` and `00011` which is treated as ten and eleven respectively. You need to prefix the radix to have it treated as binary.

The code should be modified to include:

```
// ...
wire [1:0] overflow_temp;
// ...

CLA add(.A(As), .B(Bs), .Sum(C_add), .overflow(overflow_temp[0]));
CLA addu(.A(A), .B(B), .Sum(C_addu), .overflow(overflow_temp[1]));
CLA sub(.A(As), .B(Bs2s), .Sum(C_sub), .overflow(overflow_temp[2]));
CLA subu(.A(A), .B(B2s), .Sum(C_subu), .overflow(overflow_temp[3]));

always @* begin
    case(alu_code)
    5'b00000 : C = C_add;
    5'b00001 : C = C_addu;
    5'b00010 : C = C_sub;
    5'b00011 : C = C_subu;
    endcase
end

assign over = {overflow_temp[alu_code], C[15]};

// ...
```

There might be other issues with the code. This feedback should be enough to get in in the correct direction.